# indexing an m-dimensional array in Matlab (with m not constant)

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I have an indexing problem in Matlab. Let's say that I have a m-dimensional array A with m **depending on the problem**.

Suppose I have vector with indices

```
x = [i2, ..., im]
```

and I want to take the vector

```
A(:, i_2, ..., i_m)
```

. If m is constant in all cases, it is not that difficult. You can just say

```
i_j = x(j), j = 2, ..., m
```

. Is it possible to do this without an if-loop
 (so without saying 'if m == 2 then .. if m == 3 then ...' and so on )?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be easily done converting `x` into cell array and generating a [comma-separated list](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) from that:

```
A = rand(3,3,3,3,3); % example A
x = [2 1 3 2]; % example x
ind = num2cell(x);
result = A(:, ind{:});
```

Comment: thanks, that's exactly what I want :-)

Comment: A neat little trick: you can add `':'` to the cell array where ever you want. For example: `ind = [{':'} num2cell(x)]; result = A(ind{:});`